# How to timeout a Future in Java without using Future.get() as it's a blocking operation?

Tags: java, future, callable

I have a list of futures over which i keep looping checking `Future.isDone()` and if yes, then i use `Future.get()`. But, there are cases where the thread goes on forever and to avoid this i want to timeout.

Please help me timing out a future without using `Future.get()` as its a blocking operation. Most of the questions on timing out here on stackoverflow point to `Future.get()` with a timeout inside it.

Comment: (a) check isDone until your timeout then cancel the future or (b) use the get(timeout) method in a separate thread if you don't want to block?

Comment: In addition to what @assylias suggested, you might want to look at CompletableFuture.

Comment: You can use a `CompletionService` to give you back `Future`s as they complete (with a timeout).

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) instead of plain `Future` you can use `CompletableFuture.anyOf()` method:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when any of the given CompletableFutures complete, with the same result.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = 
    CompletableFuture.anyOf(future1, future2, future3); 
combinedFuture.get();

if (future1.isDone()) { ... }
if (future2.isDone()) { ... }
if (future3.isDone()) { ... }
```

In Java 9 you have extra methods for handling timeouts e.g. [`CompletableFuture.completeOnTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeOnTimeout(T,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Comment: Hi Karol, thanks for the answer. I am looking at a solution which can help me do with this futures as I am not allowed to change the existing implementation. Also, not looking at .anyOf() as all the futures have to complete their execution. Do point me to any resource that helps me with this use case.